# What's the $f(x+iy)$ form of $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

So complex functions are sometimes written as

$$f(x+iy)=u+iv$$

where $u,v$ are functions.

What's this form for $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$?

Would one set $u=x^2+y^2$, since $x^2+y^2$ is real or $u=x^2, v=y^2$, since the $y^2$ is coordinate of imaginary part?

Answer (score 4):

If $f(z)=|z|^2$, then $u(x,y)= Re (f(z))= x^2+y^2$ and $v(x,y)=Im (f(z))=0,$ since $f(z) \in \mathbb R$ for all $z.$

Answer (score 0):

When you write $$f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$
you usually assume that $u$ and $v$ are real-valued functions, and from this it follows that $$u(x,y) = {\rm Re} (f(x+iy)) $$
$$v(x,y) = {\rm Im} (f(x+iy)) $$
If $f(x+iy) = x^2+y^2$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$ it means that that $$u(x,y) = x^2+y^2 $$
$$v(x,y) = 0 $$